# sql last name comma first null checks

Tags: mysql

I have three columns in the database that represent a person's first, middle, and last names:

```
            People
|------------------------------------------|
| First_Name  |  Last_name    | Middle_name|
|------------------------------------------|
|  John       |  Hansen       |     T      |
|   NULL      |  Smith        |    NULL    |
|  Jacob      |    NULL       |     J      |
|  Michael    |  Johnson      |    NULL    |
|------------------------------------------|
```

What is the best way to get null safe Last, First Name + Middle Name. So that from the list above I would get:

```
Hansen, John T
Smith
Jacob J
Johnson, Michael
```

So far I've got:

```
select concat_ws(', ', name_last, concat_ws(' ', name_first, name_middle)) as name from entity;
```

but it's giving me trailing `,` where I don't want them.

Comment: Oops I see that.  Let me edit.

Comment: Whew, think I got it right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the fact that `CONCAT` will return `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name), last_name, first_name)
FROM People
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0639f/4)

---

Or, now that you've edited your question to add a Middle_name column:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(last_name, ', ', COALESCE(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', middle_name),first_name,middle_name)), 
                last_name, 
                COALESCE(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', middle_name),first_name,middle_name))
FROM People
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc3603/1)

Comment: +1 This is good solution, just needs to be expanded a bit to include middle name variants.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around:
You have a fullname column containing "firstname middlename lastname"
and want to display it sorted on lastname

Made this as working, at least it works great on dutch names ("van der Boogert" but also single (artist)names.

This example trims the anmes for extra spaces, then counts the amount of spaces in the fullname so no commas are places when its only a single name (artist name)

```
SELECT
    TRIM(fullname) as originalfullname, 
    length(trim(fullname)) -length(replace(TRIM(fullname), ' ', '')) AS countedzeros,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(fullname), ' ', length(TRIM(fullname)) -length(replace(TRIM(fullname), ' ', '')))  AS first_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(fullname),  ' ', -1) AS last_name,
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(fullname),  ' ', -1),
        IF(length(TRIM(fullname)) -length(replace(TRIM(fullname), ' ', '')),', ',''),
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(fullname), ' ', length(TRIM(fullname)) -length(replace(TRIM(fullname), ' ', '')))
    ) as dispayname
    FROM catalog
    group by fullname


/*
Theo van den Boogaart => Boogaart, Theo van den
Hergé => Hergé
Jhonny Smith => Smith, Johnny

*/
```